# Geography cryptic clue

Tags: cryptic-clues, geography

I’m doing a cryptic English towns and cities quiz and I have 1 clue left. The town or city is further south than Newcastle and further north than Hartlepool.

The clue is:

> "Mars is on land surrounded by water"

Comment: Could it be Marx instead of Mars? The "land surrounded by water" seems rather unambiguous.

Comment: I don’t have a number of letters

Comment: It could be fen(https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define+marsh&oq=define+marsh&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6668j1j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#dobs=fen)

Comment: Except that "fen" isn't the name of an English town or city, the area known as the Fens is further south than the range OP specified, it seems to have nothing to do with Mars, and it doesn't really mean "land surrounded by water".

Comment: @TomHardy, is it definitely *English* rather than e.g. Northern Irish or even Scottish? (I think there's a teeny little bit of Scotland further south than Newcastle.)

Comment: Not so teeny, actually. I think all of the southern coast in Dumfries and Galloway qualifies. (For what it's worth, I still supspect it's Carlisle and Mars is a misprint for Marx.)

Comment: And Carl is a misprint for Karl, right? :-)

Comment: _Touché!_ I admit that trying to hammer the clue until it fits isn't fair, but we don't know of which quality the other clues in the quiz are. I couldn't find the quiz, but I've checked some quizzes that I think could be similar to the one in question and they often use homophones without indication.

Comment: There are no other faults in the quiz.

Comment: I vote to close "Mars is on land by water" (10)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that

> the answer of Ram's Island is correct. It is an island in the North Irish Lough Neagh.

**How you get this answer:**

> Mars is an anagram of Rams. Also "is on land" is mentioned in the riddle and if you put "is" and "land" together you get "island". It is also fully surrounded by water as the riddle says. This is all supposing that it is places in Great Britain as apposed to towns and cities in England.

**More information:**

> Ram's Island is a 1.5 km island (point to point) roughly 1.7 km offshore. It is along the latitude in between of Newcastle and Hartlepool. Extra information can be found at [the Ram's Island Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram%27s_Island,_Northern_Ireland).

**P.S.** for further information for my interest in research, please could you tell me what website/app this is on. Thankyou.

Comment: Which one is the anagram indicator here?

Comment: @Sid maybe 'is' is the anagram indicator. It's an easy anagram so a very thin indicator should suffice...